# How to get ``` /file.txt ``` by using python file split?

Tags: python

I am trying to join the url(absolute path and relative path) using python.but It doesn't work as I have expected.

```
base_url = https://someurl/something/repo #values are coming from nfig.yml
filename = /home/tests/fixtures/python_app/dist/python_app-any.whl
url = urljoin(base_url, filename.split('/')[-1])
print("url:",url)
```

current result:

```
url: https://someurl/something/python_app-any.whl
```

expected result:

```
url: https://someurl/something/repo/python_app-any.whl
```

I do not want to use `slash` at the end of `base_url`

Can someone guide me here with other possibilities?

Comment: what is `urljoin`? Also, please provide a proper Python code in your example.

Comment: Your URL is malformed. `https://someurl//something/repo` has a double forward slash between `someurl` and `something`.

Comment: Can you just concatenate `base_url + "/" + url`?

Comment: i would also do concat. This url python lib is not the best of design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```py
filepath = "/a/b/c/d"
```

you can get `"d"` with [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

```py
base_url = "https://someurl//something/repo"  # N.B. something is wrong with this...
filepath = "/home/tests/fixtures/python_app/dist/python_app-any.whl"

resulting_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, os.path.basename(filepath))
```

Comment: Thanks Adam for quick response. Still I am getting the same result ```url: https://someurl/something/python_app-any.whl```

Comment: @jignapatel have you looked at my comment on your question, and my comment in my own code block? Your URL is malformed, which is causing `urllib.parse.urljoin` to treat it differently than you expect.

Comment: Hey Adam. Yes I saw it. Sorry I didn't put all the code here. The ```base_url``` output is coming from two values(one is path and second url with slash and without slash from configuration file). when we do concatenate```base_url:'https://someurl/ '+'/something/repo'``` It may take double slash too and this should be resolved at the time of ```urljoin``` in ```url```

Comment: @jignapatel "This should be resolved at the time of `urljoin`" but you can see that it's not, right? `assert urljoin("http://a//b/c", "d") == 'http://a/b/d'`. This was trivial to test...

Answer (score -1):

I created user-defined function for urljoin as below :
It's working fine.

```
    def urljoin(base_url, path):
       base_url = base_url if base_url.endswith('/') else base_url + '/'
       path = path[1:] if path.startswith('/') else path
       return base_url + path

    x=urljoin('https://hi/','hello') # (base_url, path)
    print(x)
    y=urljoin(x, 'test') # (base_url,filename)
    print(y)
```

result:

```
    x = https://hi/hello
    y = https://hi/hello/test
```

Can anyone guide me to write unit test for this code ?